# Difference between ODBC and Netezza engine

Tags: sas, odbc, netezza

I am loading SAS tables into Netezza and I am using a libname with the ODBC connection to connect to netezza like this:

```
libname myConnection odbc noprompt="server=xxxx; DRIVER={NetezzaSQL}; port=xxxx;database=xxxx; username=xxxx;password=xxxx;";
```

I do it with SAS/Access Interface to ODBC because I do not have SAS/Access Interface to Netezza.

Are there any disadvantages of using ODBC engine over the Netezza engine?

Comment: this is for oracle but will make sense for netezza too. http://support.sas.com/kb/31/648.html. there might be slight differences about which I will not be too oncerned

Comment: @Kiran it states the types of things you can do such as using the bulkload option, but this option already exists with SAS/ACCESS interface to ODBC

Comment: it is just as example, but i mean to say there may be minor differences about which you may not be too worried

Comment: @Kiran in this article: https://www.ibmbigdatahub.com/blog/netezza-and-sas-integration-best-practices where he talks about ODBC it states why SAS/ACCESS to Netezza would be best. Technically all I want to do is load data into Netezza. So would Netezza engine instead of ODBC cause for better performance in loading big data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends. 
see the below link  for the paper on SAS connections in relation to netezza
sas.com/partners/directory/ibm/NetezzaDWAppliances-withSAS.pdf

In this paper, it describes SAS/Access for ODBC is also available, but provides lower performance as it does not ‘push down’ as much of the SAS code or PROC SQL as SQL to Netezza. SAS/Access for ODBC does not support SAS 9.3 in-database processing.

when you are writing an implicit pass through or a datastep the code is not sent to database for processing in 9.3 and about 9.4 i do not have idea.

So performance will be impacted when you are using implicit pass through and looking for in-database processing

If you are just moving your data from SAS to Netezza, impact may not be significant but I have not tested both of them separately so I cannot tell for sure

Comment: thanks for this info. The tables we are working with are 100 of millions of rows. So it might be worth it to test both ODBC and NETEZZA for performance, which is what I'll try to do. I appreciate the help!

Comment: In my experience the push-down capabilities of the sas engine out-of-the-box is not great. It constantly opens extra connections to the database (one connection only is key to push-down) and libnames under different schemas are not always using the same connection, even if you make them all ‘global’.

Comment: In short: it is almost the same amount of work to write pass through sql yourself and only use the odbc connect. Only real difference is if you use a LOT of sas formats. Please note that the Netezza connect IS using odbc under the covers, only difference when push comes is push-down.